# Loading into a target table

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Today I tried Bonobo + SQLAlchemy (for the first time), so it's bound to be full of bad practices. However, this is working code. I'm hoping for some feedback to for doing it correctly.

I started out using the SQLAlchemy extension for Bonobo, but I ran into limitations, so I wrote my own loader. My DB is SQLite3, so it doesn't support multiple connections.

What this does is read from one table, do a simple transformation and load into a target table with a different table structure.

SQLite database:

```
CREATE TABLE sys_batch (
    batch_id        INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    batch_name      VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) );

CREATE TABLE sys_batch_tgt (
    batch_id        INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name_of_batch   VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) );
```

Python code:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

import bonobo
#import bonobo_sqlalchemy

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///C:/Py/bonobo/coolstuff.db')
Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

# Tables
sys_batch = Base.classes.sys_batch
sys_batch_tgt = Base.classes.sys_batch_tgt

#def get_services():
#   return {'sqlalchemy.pgengine': sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///C:/Py/bonobo/coolstuff.db')}

def extract_sys_batch():
    conn = engine.connect()
    s = select([sys_batch])
    result = conn.execute(s)
    #conn.close()
    row = result.fetchone()
    yield row

# convert incoming SQLAlchemy "ProxyRow" to a dict, so we can manipulate it.
def tfm_0(row):
    tgt_row = {}
    tgt_row['batch_id'] = row['batch_id']
    tgt_row['name_of_batch'] = row['batch_name']
    return tgt_row

def tfm_1(row):
    row['batch_id'] = row['batch_id'] + 100
    return row

def ldr_1(row):
    # write to target
    session = Session(engine)
    thing = sys_batch_tgt(**row)
    session.add(thing)
    session.commit()

def get_graph(**options):

    return bonobo.Graph(
        extract_sys_batch,
        tfm_0,
        tfm_1,
        ldr_1,
        bonobo.PrettyPrinter(),
    )

# The __main__ block actually execute the graph.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = bonobo.get_argument_parser()

    #each transformation is its own thread, so we have to open/close in there.
    #conn = engine.connect()

    with bonobo.parse_args(parser) as options:
        bonobo.run(get_graph(**options)) #, services=get_services(**options)

    #conn.close()
```

Comment: So `get_graph` ignores all options?